# NGINX and Vuejs serving static files

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nginx

I have a basic node server that serves built vuejs application.

The server is running on localhost:3000

Nginx is set to listen on port 80

The app is deployed on the local IP.

**nginx config**:

```
 upstream nodejs {
        server localhost:3000;
 }

 server {
       listen 80;
       server_name localhost;
       root /mnt/data/app/server/public;

       location / {
            try_files $uri @nodejs;
       }

       location @nodejs {
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_pass http://nodejs;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host ;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       }
}
```

In index.html all static files are loaded like

**css**

```
 href="/css/chunk_name.css"
```

**js**

```
 src="/js/chunk_name.js"
```

The issue is that all of those static files are loading over HTTPS

Check the screenshot

[image]

If I try to load a single file but replacing HTTPS with HTTP, the file is loaded normally.

I don't know if I am missing something in the config, or it is something else. Any help is  appritiated

Comment: You shouldn't be using Node.js to serve static files in production at all. In this case you should have Nginx set up to serve the static files and proxy to your Node.js service for any dynamic content.

Comment: What's your issue here? resources over https?

Comment: Your nginx is not configured to listen/serve anything over https. Where/Why do you try to access the static files over https?! And why do you have "localhost" as server_name and do requests to the IP?! Need more details to clarify.

Comment: @Marc That is strange, I have no clue why it is requesting over HTTPS when it should be HTTP. The initial request is sent to http://10.64.93.111, and index.html is returned, however, the static files in that HTML are loaded via HTTPS for whatever reason. Changed the server name to the localhost, still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Config your nginx to serve the static file

```
location ~ ^/(css|js)/  {
    access_log  off;
    expires     30d;
}
```

Comment: More details would be great, why he should do it this way. Further more, you have noticed that in his nginx config, no https/tls/ssl server/service is configured? How should nginx server files over https, if nginx dosnt listen for that service/port?

Comment: Looks like it works. Quick question, how would I add a subpath, for example, not to serve from / but from /app or similar route?

Comment: Your solutation is listed as bad-practice from the offical nginx docs: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#root-inside-location-block @lejhbah You should not do it this way